# Solidity block.timestamp vulnerability

Tags: security, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I've been analysing the contract in [this github link](https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/main/examples/sol/BD_false.sol), which contains false positives for the bug [Block State Dependency](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-120).

The lines [68](https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/45430325557db85f32d034b6aca70a4d9cc27d66/examples/sol/BD_false.sol#L68), [71](https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/45430325557db85f32d034b6aca70a4d9cc27d66/examples/sol/BD_false.sol#L71) and [84](https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/45430325557db85f32d034b6aca70a4d9cc27d66/examples/sol/BD_false.sol#L84) of the contract seem to have this bug, but they are marked in [this annotation](https://github.com/SoftSec-KAIST/Smartian/blob/main/examples/NOTE.md) as false positives.

Can someone please explain on why this are false positives and not true positives?

EDIT: The contract code below

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address owner) returns(uint);
}


contract Owned {
    address public owner;

    function Owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    address newOwner;

    function changeOwner(address _newOwner) onlyOwner {
        newOwner = _newOwner;
    }

    function acceptOwnership() {
        if (msg.sender == newOwner) {
            owner = newOwner;
        }
    }
}

contract TokenReceivable is Owned {
    event logTokenTransfer(address token, address to, uint amount);

    function claimTokens(address _token, address _to) onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        Token token = Token(_token);
        uint balance = token.balanceOf(this);
        if (token.transfer(_to, balance)) {
            logTokenTransfer(_token, _to, balance);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

contract FunFairSale is Owned, TokenReceivable {
    uint public deadline =  1499436000; // July 7th, 2017; 14:00 GMT
    uint public startTime = 1498140000; // June 22nd, 2017; 14:00 GMT
    uint public capAmount = 125000000 ether;

    // Don't allow contributions when the gas price is above
    // 50 Gwei to discourage gas price manipulation.
    uint constant MAX_GAS_PRICE = 50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 wei;

    function FunFairSale() {}

    function shortenDeadline(uint t) onlyOwner {
        // Used to shorten the deadline once (if) we've hit the soft cap.
        if (t > deadline) throw;
        deadline = t;
    }

    function () payable {
        // Don't encourage gas price manipulation.
        if (tx.gasprice > MAX_GAS_PRICE) throw;
        if (block.timestamp < startTime || block.timestamp >= deadline) throw;
        if (this.balance >= capAmount) throw;
        if (this.balance + msg.value >= capAmount) {
            deadline = block.timestamp;
        }
    }

    function withdraw() onlyOwner {
        if (!owner.call.value(this.balance)()) throw;
    }

    function setCap(uint _cap) onlyOwner {
        capAmount = _cap;
    }

    function setStartTime(uint _startTime, uint _deadline) onlyOwner {
        if (block.timestamp >= startTime) throw;
        startTime = _startTime;
        deadline = _deadline;
    }

}
```

Line 68 is

```
if (block.timestamp < startTime || block.timestamp >= deadline) throw;
```

Line 71 is

```
deadline = block.timestamp;
```

Line 84 is

```
if (block.timestamp >= startTime) throw;
```

Comment: Please provide the code here in this site

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

A `block.timestamp` value can be manipulated by a dishonest miner. Usually to an extent of few seconds on Ethereum, or generally few percent of the block time on any EVM-compatible PoW network.

In some cases, that can lead to serious consequences. Especially when the block timestamp is used to generate a pseudorandom number (e.g. for a lottery), then a dishonest miner can determine what timestamp they should publish the block with, in order to get a desired number as a result (and win the lottery with their own transaction using this number).

But in some cases, few seconds won't make a difference. Like in the linked example, where the sale is open between two specified dates. It simply doesn't matter if the block (effectively opening the sale) is published with a timestamp that is few seconds earlier or later.

---

However, a static analysis is not able to take business logic into consideration. So to be safe, it points out all occurrences of `block.timestamp` as potentially unsafe. So then the code authors decided to mark these cases as false positives.